# C# How to make a standalone version of windows app with SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2013

So I got this windows app in C# which displays FAQ. All the data are stored in SQL Server. I used an **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** to build connection between my app and the database. Now the app is finished and I don't know how to make it standalone.

I need the app to run even if the PC where I'll copy the app doesn't have SQL Server. I tried to copy the `.mdf` file to `bin/debug` folder and make some changes to `app.config` but it doesn't work or maybe I just don't know the proper way to change `app.config` connection string because it is auto generated by the **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**. I'm an intern and this is my requirement to pass. please help

Here's the current `app.config` connection config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbFAQEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-CK86A2B;initial catalog=dbFAQ;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="dbFAQEntities1" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-CK86A2B;initial catalog=dbFAQ;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Does each C have a separate database or do you want all PCs to share a single database?If each PC requires it own database then you must do 2 things.1) Clone Database which will create a schema of the database.  2)   Install schema on each PC which will build a database on each PC.Just copying the mdf file does nothing unless you attach the mdf file to a database. The default database you are using is : initial catalog=dbFAQ which is the attached database.When a database is attached the sql server binds the mdf file to the database.You application simply connects to the database (not the file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to make the app run on PCs which does NOT have Sql Server installed.

A simple answer: You cannot

It is just like asking to make .mp3 files stand alone without a player.

Comment: So a more practical answer is: you deploy standalone SQL Server with the app.